# Why doesn't this work (Python)?

Tags: python, primes

So I'm trying to learn Python using some tutorials, and I decided to create my own exercise. I wanted to create a script that figures out how many prime numbers there are between 1 and 1000, as well as printing the prime numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
numberlist = []
a = 1
prime = True
while a < 1000:
    a = a + 1
    for divisor in range(2,a):
        if a/divisor==int(a/divisor):
            prime=False
        if prime == True:
            print a
            numberlist.append(a)

print "Number of prime numbers between 1 and 1000:", len(numberlist)
```

However, when I start the application, it returns

"Number of prime numbers between 1 and 1000: 0"

I don't know what I've done wrong. Can someone please clarify what I screwed up on?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: So now the code looks like this, but the same problem is occurring:

```
numberlist = []

a = 1

for a in xrange(1, 1000):
    for divisor in range(2,a):
        if a % divisor == 0:
           prime=False
        else:
           prime=True
if prime == True:
    print a
    numberlist.append(a)

print "Number of prime numbers between 1 and 1000:", len(numberlist)
```

Comment: Just to let you know, you can significantly improve this algorithm by doing `for divisor in numberlist` (if you make `a` start at 2, or do `for divisor in numberlist[1:]` and just start with `numberlist=[1]`).

Comment: And with a break statement after prime=False.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with this code. First, `a/divisor == int(a/divisor)` is always `True`, because division in Python is integral (you will always get an integer result). Use `a % divisor == 0` instead.

Another problem is that `prime = True` is outside the loop, meaning that as soon as one value is declared not prime, no more values can be prime! (`prime` will never get set back to `True` anywhere.)

A third issue, more of style, is that it is preferred to use a `for ... in` loop in python, eg

```
for a in xrange(1, 1000):
    for divisor in xrange(2, a): ...
```

Edit: Regarding your modified code: your `if` statement at the very end is not indented, and therefore not part of the `for` loop. It is only being executed once, after the loop ends, meaning `prime` will be the last value set (where `a` is `999`, not a prime). You want to indent the entire `if` statement to be in your inner `for` loop. You could condense this, though:

```
for a in xrange(1, 1000):
    for divisor in xrange(2, a):
        if a % divisor == 0:
            break
    else:
        print a
        numberlist.append(a)
```

Note that this uses the `for ... else` clause. Putting `else` at the end of a `for` loop will cause that `else` block to run *only if* the loop is not broken by `break`.

As a further comment, starting the whole loop at `1` will have `1` in the list, but [`1` is not a prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Answer (score 3):

a/divisor evaluates to an int since both a and divisor are ints, so a/divisor == int(a/divisor) is always true. Try checking the remainder after division... the modulus... I think that in Python, maybe

```
  if a % divisor == 0:
     ...
```

This basically says "if the remainder after dividing a by divisor is zero, then".

Comment: This is changed on the version 3.0. "An expression like 1/2 returns a float. Use 1//2 to get the truncating behavior. (The latter syntax has existed for years, at least since Python 2.2.)" [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Answer (score 3):

You never reset `prime` to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to reset `prime`'s value to `True` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you when you get further along to know that there are 168 primes less than 1000.